Uniqueness of permutation preserving order
Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $S\subset\mathbb{N}$ and let $f$ and $g$ be two bijective functions from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ to $S$. If both functions are strictly increasing, does it follow that $f=g$?
Intuitively this only says that there is a unique permutation that respects the order in S. We have $f(1)<\cdots<f(n)$ and $g(1)<\cdots<g(n)$, but assuming that $f(i)<g(i)$ or $g(i)<f(i)$ for some $i$ I don't come to any contradiction. Thanks in advance.

Use the well ordering of $\mathbb{N}$ or its subsets.
Since we have surjectivity, $f(1)$ must be the smallest element of the set $S$, and similarly for $g(1)$. Thus, we have established that $f(1)=g(1)$.
Now, we take $f(2)$, and similarly we have it to be the second smallest element in $S$, as $f(2) \neq f(1)$ from injectivity, and we apply this similarly for $g(2)$.
We continue this process via induction until we reach $f(n)=g(n)$, and thus we have $f=g$.

Here's one way, which is another phrasing of @Aaa Lol_dude's answer.  Write $S= \{s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_n\}$ where $s_i < s_j$ when $i<j$.  The function $\sigma: \{1,2, \ldots, n\} \to S$ by $\sigma(i)=s_i$ is clearly bijective and increasing.  We prove that if $f: \{1,2, \ldots, n\} \to S$ is bijective and increasing then $f=\sigma$.
Since $f$ is onto there is an $i$ with $f(i)=s_1$, the least element of $S$.  Clearly we must have $i=1$ else $f(i-1)$ is below $f(i)=s_1$, which is impossible.  Hence $f(1)=\sigma(1)$.  Now apply the same argument to $f|_{\{2, 3, \ldots, n\}}$ as a map $\{2, 3, \ldots, n\} \to S-\{s_1\}$ to prove that $f(2)=\sigma(2)$.  This bit is legal because $f$ is bijective: deleting $1$ from the domain and $s_1$ from the codomain leaves behind a legitimate function.  Continuing, we get $f=\sigma$.  Thus there is only one such map, as any such map must be equal to the "model" $\sigma$.
